# "Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 587" delivering mails from Sidekiq in staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, staging

I tried to send many user emails from a worker using Sidekiq but when I enqueued the worker I got an error `Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 587`, doing the same process on localhost works fine.

**Piece of worker code**

```
def send_mails(users)
  users.each do |user|
     WelcomeMailer.presale_users({email: user.email}).deliver
  end
end
```

**staging.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: ENV['SES_ADDRESS'],
  port: 587,
  domain: 'domain.com',
  user_name: ENV['SES_USER_NAME'],
  password: ENV['SES_PASSWORD']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `address` is `nil`.

Are your environment variables being read correctly?

Maybe try outputting them in the logger.

Comment: it is a strange behaviour because I can send a single mail by running this line in the rails console:

WelcomeMailer.presale_users({email: user.email}).deliver